# Face Recognition with IOS/ Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, augmented-reality, face-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I perform facial recogntion on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020842/how-can-i-perform-facial-recogntion-on-ios)

Face Detection is possible with the iPhone using IOS5. How can we implement the face recognition.

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV is great for face recognition, but I believe that Core Image is an easier alternative. Core Image has classes like [CIDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and [CIFaceFeature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html)

Check out these tutorials for Core Image face detection:

- [iOS 5 Face Detection with Core Image](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/22/ios-5-face-detection-with-core-image/)
- [Easy Face Detection with Core Image in iOS 5](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Detection is not recognition.